# Is there any documentation for Google Cloud Messaging with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging, channel

Currently I'm working on a project that requires me to send push notification via GCM; on the server side I'm using Ruby on Rails. I am unable to find any proper tutorial or documentation for the same.

I have no idea on how how should I go by writing models for GCM users with userids / device id mapping. What should I do in case the user in logged out of the app or two users use the same devisce and same app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [tutorial](http://mateuyabar.com/blog/android/rubyonrails/gcm/2015/05/13/Google-Cloud_Messaging-with-Ruby-On-Rails.html) for creating your server using *Ruby On Rails*. This tutorial also provides the code for the Android Client.

Here is another sample [tutorial](https://github.com/mateuyabar/blog_gcm_and_ror) GCM code with server created using *Ruby on Rails* and the client code is an android app.

Comment: thanks for the tutorials :) i,m still not sure how should i map my device ids with registration token and in case if user logs out of app / unistalls it then what will happen to the registration ids ?